# Cannot launch SDL2 app through Clion on wsl2 using VcXsrv

Tags: c, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sdl-2, clion

I'm trying to run SDL2 window app in CLion on wsl2 (ubuntu 20) however facing these issues.

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
The path /dev/dri/ cannot be opened or is not available
```

I'm using VcXsrv for remote display which works fine when running the executable through terminal. However running in Clion doesn't. So I'm looking for some way around it (if possible)